# Global resources in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to upgrade a Xamarin 2.x solution to Xamarin 4.8.

I need to [add Global Resources in an App.xaml file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/devfish/global-resources-in-xamarin-forms-no-app-xaml-create-one) in order to [support the Dark/Light themes on iOS](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/modernizing-ios-apps-dark-mode-xamarin/). This means that a new App class will be introduced.

My problem is that I already have a static App class defined the shared forms project.

```
public static class App
{
    private static Page mainPage;
    ....
}
```

I will need to adapt the existing code, but I can't find any guidance to do that.

Comment: You could check the docs about how to update an existing XF project . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-xamarin-forms-apps

Comment: Nothing about replacing a static class with a new Application derived one.

Comment: You could create a new App class and delete the old one .

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem - you can create a new Application page. Follow the steps below:

**1. Right click on the project and press Add:**

You will get the dialogue below - press on ContentPage and name it 'App'.

**2. Replace the content page like so by replacing the content page with the `Application` tag:**

[image]

**3. Add Application.Resources:**

[image]

Once you've added Application.Resources (and optionally a ResourceDictionary) you can import all of your old data into this new App.xaml.

**4. In the code-behind file - make sure you are deriving from the Application - not from content page. Change this in all references in your project.**

[image]

Now you have officially replaced your old App.xaml file - if you have any problems tell me in the comments. If I solved your problem mark this as the solution - thank you.